# Problems with transactionScope and ServiceBus in production environment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope, unit-of-work, servicebus

I have seen other with similar issues but I have yet to find a working solution.

I'm using a transaction while calling Database and ServiceBus.

I'm using a UnitOfWork/EntityFramework for my database.

Here is my code

```
/*Creating the list and adding to UnitOfWork repository*/
....
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            ExportGroups(myGroupList);
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

And here is a snippet from the ExportGroups function

```
public void ExportGroups(IEnumerable<Group> groups)
{
     /*Generating BrokeredMessage message*/
     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            MessagingFactory factory = CreateMessagingFactory(...);
            if (factory != null)
            {
                var sender = factory.CreateMessageSender(topicName);
                sender.Send(message);
            }
        }).Wait();

}
```

This works without any issues in my development environment. But when we put it into production I get the following error

"System.InvalidOperationException: Local transactions are not supported with other resource managers/DTC."

The DTC is enabled on the machine and we use it to process other transactions just fine, though none of them use the ServiceBus in them.

[EDIT = Added stack trace]

```
Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpResourceManager.EnlistAsyncResult..ctor(SbmpResourceManager resourceManager, Transaction transaction, IRequestSessionChannel channel, SbmpMessageCreator messageCreator, Action`1 partitionInfoSetter, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpResourceManager.BeginEnlist(Transaction transaction, IRequestSessionChannel channel, SbmpMessageCreator messageCreator, Action`1 partitionInfoSetter, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpTransactionalAsyncResult`1.<>c__DisplayClass3e.<GetAsyncSteps>b__38(TIteratorAsyncResult thisPtr, TimeSpan t, AsyncCallback c, Object s)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.Start()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.EndSendCommand(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.OnEndSend(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.RunSynchronously()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.Send(TrackingContext trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 messages, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at ....GroupService.ExportGroups(IEnumerable<Group> groups)
```

Comment: As far as I know you [can't achieve this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15528668/997668) (See part of the answer under the **Update**). Service Bus [doesn't support DTC](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/817c325e-b439-49ac-aec8-98c0c7c83cc0/local-transactions-are-not-supported-with-other-resource-managersdtc?forum=servbus). If you're in `Windows Azure` you could use [this approach](http://geekswithblogs.net/asmith/archive/2012/04/02/149176.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Michael.
I noticed both these threads in my search for answers. What puzzles me is that it's working when running the system from visual studio in debug mode. That is what lead me to beleive that it was indeed possible.

Comment: On a side note. After some local fault tracing and testing It seems that when running it over Visual Studio it's not even using the DTC, this is to me even more puzzeling. I stopped the DTC service on my development environment and the functionality still works. Works with updating both entities and it handles the rollback with the database if the ExportGroups call throws an exception

Comment: Another strange development on the matter.
I added this to use an NInject block (based on tips from a coworker)
Once deployed I managed to get this working once, it saved to database and it pushed the message to the service bus.

When retrying the same process we are back on th above error.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()
{
    //Database call

    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        sender.Send(message);
        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are not supported across different Windows Azure Services. That said there are many [ways to send messages to service bus with transactional guarantees](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clemensv/archive/2012/07/30/transactions-in-windows-azure-with-service-bus-an-email-discussion.aspx).

HTH!
Sree