# How to make Azure Service Bus client to not participate to the ambient transaction when sending a message

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azureservicebus

I understand that DTC's are not supported by Azure Service Bus and if you try to do so you get an exception like this: '*Local transactions are not supported with other resource managers/DTC.*'

My problem is that I need to send a message to a service bus and the code might be executed within a transaction scope together with possible DB-operations. But the service bus doesn't need to be particularly part of this transaction; so, DTC is not really needed here. However, the service bus client seems to participate automatically to the ambient transaction which elevates the transaction to a DTC.

Examples:

This runs correctly (service bus code is the only one in the transaction):

```
        using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //A simple Azure Bus operation
            var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
            var queueClient = new QueueClient(builder);
            var messageBody = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello"));
            messageBody.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            queueClient.SendAsync(messageBody).GetAwaiter().GetResult();                

            tx.Complete();
        }
```

But from the moment another system participates (here an Sql connection) the "*DTC are not supported by Azure Service Bus*"-exception is thrown:

```
        using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //A simple DB operation
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([Name]) values ('Hello')", sqlConnection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //A simple Azure Bus operation
            var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
            var queueClient = new QueueClient(builder);
            var messageBody = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello"));
            messageBody.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            queueClient.SendAsync(messageBody).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            queueClient.CloseAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            sqlConnection.Close();

            tx.Complete();
        }
```

This error is understandable and already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298271/problems-with-transactionscope-and-servicebus-in-production-environment).
But is there a way to tell the service bus client to ignore the ambient transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to suppress the ambient transaction and wrap your Service Bus code with the following:

```
public async Task Method()
{
  SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
  sqlConnection.Open();

  using (var tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
  {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]([Name]) values 
('Hello')", sqlConnection);
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

    using (var tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
       var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
       var queueClient = new QueueClient(builder);
       var messageBody = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello"));
       messageBody.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
       queueClient.SendAsync(messageBody).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

       queueClient.CloseAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

       tx.Complete();
    }

    tx.Complete();
  }
  sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Note that

1. You should not be recreating your queue client each time. Keep it around for performance considerations.
2. Do not use asynchronous APIs in a synchronous code. Rather convert your method to be async. SQL operations are IO-bound just as Service Bus. It's better to have the method to be asynchronous.

Comment: thank you for the reply. But this will also suppress the transaction of the eventual DB operations, right? My DB operations still need the ambient transaction.

Comment: Note that I've included only the messaging (Service Bus) operations in the scope suppression? Your operations would be in the outer scope. I'll update the answer to reflect that better.

Comment: Oh, I see, that works indeed for me. Thanks for the answer!